# MsgBox vbOKCancel leaves 1 or 2 in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am using an inputbox with type 8 (cell reference / range). Part of the validation of the selected range is with the MsgBox below.

The problem is that when you select a wrong range and the MsgBox prompts you, if you click `Ok` it leaves the number 2 in the cell, and if you click `Cancel` it leaves the number 1 in the cell.

```
ElseIf myRange.Value = "" Or myRange.Value = 0 Then   

  '... 

   myRange = MsgBox("Please Select a Valid Code. Try again?", vbOKCancel + vbQuestion)
   If myRange = vbCancel Then 'No retry
       Exit Sub
   Else 'retry
       Run "MyCellToCorrect"
   End If

Else
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the return value of `MsgBox`, which will be either `vbOK` (1) or `vbCancel` (2), to the range. You should be assigning it to a numeric variable instead, and then testing that variable:

```
Dim Res As Integer
....

Res = MsgBox("Please Select a Valid Code. Try again?", vbOKCancel + vbQuestion)
If Res = vbCancel Then 'No retry
    Exit Sub
Else 'retry
    Run "MyCellToCorrect"
End If
```

Comment: I think your suggestion is true. I am going to test it and see.

Comment: @Ken White Yes, that suggestion/ solution works just fine and it really helped me, cause MsgBox is sometimes a little bit tricky^^